# How do I 'dereference' a closure?

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees

So I'm parsing an expression tree, but I've come across an anomaly. Given the expression:

```
Int32 five = 5;

var query = Z<MyPersonTable>.QueryVia<IPersonQuery>()
    .Where(person => five == 5);
```

When I parse the `five` field, rather than getting an actual number, I get:

`Program.Hosting.TestService.P+<>;c__DisplayClass0`

which I recognize must be a closure, but how do I get the actual value out of it?

Here's my parser:

```
    private static XElement Parse(ConstantExpression constant)
    {
        return new XElement("CONSTANT",
            new XAttribute("TYPE", constant.Type),
                constant.Value);
    }
```

which normally works for other values, but not when I pass in a closure.

Comment: The expression tree will contain a field node; how do you get the value out of any other field node? That is, if you had `C c = new C(); c.field = 5; ... Where(person => c.field == 5)` how would you get the value out of the field node?

Comment: Is there somewhere within `ConstantExpression` can I determine that the constant is a field? I can figure it out from there if I can just somehow determine that what I'm looking at is a field.

Comment: I'm not following your line of thought here. The field isn't a constant; the field is a field. The only "constants" are the literal 5 and the reference to the closure class.

Comment: Ah, it just hit me. that makes perfect sense. Thank you!

Comment: You are very welcome. I wish we had named "Constant" instead as "Value"; it would be slightly less confusing. The closure semantics of expression trees are confusing enough to begin with!